# change background color of entire react application

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm currently working on creating a website built with react, and I can't seem to figure out where I would place the code to ensure that the background color of the application is always 'bg-dark'.

It is working in some places, however when certain elements load / extend past the scroll limit the background goes back to being white.

How would I enforce that the root element / `<body></body>` always has the "#090909" background and not white?

I can currently manually set each component to have a dark background by using `<Component className="bg-dark">` but I want to do this site-wide.

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
//import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer.js'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore, createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore'
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import firebaseConfig from './config/firebaseConfig'
import firebase from './config/firebaseConfig'
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './assets/app.scss'

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirestore, getFirebase})),
    reduxFirestore(firebase, firebaseConfig)
  )
);

const rffConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true,
}

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rffConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
        <App />
      </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

and index.css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #090909 !important;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

Comment: import index.css line is commented

Comment: haha, thanks man thats a stupid mistake - very new to react !

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this in your CSS file

```
body {
    background-color: #090909;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - where would I place this?

Comment: in your css file

Comment: index.css? That already contains this line and it doesn't work.

Comment: then try adding `background-color: #090909 !important`

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: have you imported the index.css file in root of your app

Comment: Yep, `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/index.css"/>` is in index.html

Comment: if you are putting the css through html then your css file should be in public folder